# How to add more actions to existing controller in Symfony via console?

Tags: php, symfony

I am looking for a way to add new actions to existing controller via php app/console.

Have searched using google, was not able to find any solutions on this.

It is possible to add actions to a new controller via generate:controller, but I am looking for solution on how to add a new action say to DefaultController.php via console instead of manually typing it in editor.

Comment: What is the problem when adding actions using an editor? You need one anyways to define the logic for your actions

Comment: You need write custom routing, which gets routes from DB for example and write console command for adding records in DB

Comment: @NicoHaase well it saves time as slow typist.

Comment: @zalex I do not have DB yet. Just want to add a new action that shows a template as what it is doing during generate:controller command.